# Dividing array elements in one array with another - Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `ym` and `r_div` with shapes (110,) and (120,). I want to divide `ym` with `r_div`, i.e. the first element of `ym` gets divided by the first element of `r_div`, the second element by second element and so on. I tried converting both the arrays to lists and dividing them, but no avail. Tried a `truediv` and `map`, but not able to get the values in `map`.

This is what I tried so far:

```
from operator import truediv
norm_y = map(truediv, ym_list, first)
```

and converting them to lists, and dividing them, which resulted in a `TypeError`.

The arrays don't match in shapes, but I want to use only the first 110 elements of `r_div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice `r_div` to get the first 110 values before you divide:

```
ym / r_div[:110]
```

The `/` operator does division element-wise on NumPy arrays.

Comment: "true division" usually refers to the non-floored version: i.e., the one that corresponds to `/` rather than `//` (in Python 3, at least).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response @ajcr. I tried that. The resultant array is of shape (110, 110). I want it to be (110,). Basically, in `//` or `/`, every element in `ym` is getting divided by every element in `r_div`. the resultant array should have elements as first element = first of `ym`/first of `r_div`, second element = second of `ym`/second of `r_div`, and so on.

Comment: @magnus_prime: if your arrays `ym` and `r_div` are both one-dimensional, I don't see how the division will create a two-dimensional array - are you certain that both only have one dimension?

Comment: @ajcr : Sorry, got it! I made a typo while copying your code in the variable names! Thanks.